# Передача табличных данных из представления в контроллер ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

Суть в том, что в представление передаётся следующая модель:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<OrderViewModel> Orders { get; set; }
    public PageInfo PageInfo { get; set; }
}
```

В самом представлении выводится коллекция Orders в конструкции `foreach`:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("OrdersAction", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
 {
    ..........
    @foreach (var o in Model.Orders)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => o.Selected)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => o.Id)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => o.UserName)</td>
        ..........
    </tr>
    }
    <button name="action" value="confirm">Подтвердить</button><br>
    <button name="action" value="cancel">Отменить</button><br>
    .....
    <div class="btn-group">
    @Html.PageLinks(Model.PageInfo, x => Url.Action("Orders", new { page = x }))
    </div>
 }
```

В представлении используется пагинация(хелпер `@Html.PageLinks()`), если это имеет значение.
Не могу сообразить как получать в контроллере коллекцию `Orders`.

Comment: В каком именно контроллере?

Comment: На который ссылается форма Admin/OrdersAction

Comment: А как Вы ее получали в методе Orders? Также и получайте ее в контроллере Admin.

Comment: [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<OrderViewModel> Orders) -что послал, то и прими.

Answer (score 3):

Принять коллекцию данных для преобразования в вид модели, я так понял? Если так, то я сталкивался с подобной проблемой и не один час ломал голову, в итоге получилось нечто подобное:

```
<div class="row row-counter">
                    <input hidden type="text" name="adreses[@i].id" value="@adreses[i].id">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" name="adreses[@i].key" class="form-control" value="@adreses[i].key" placeholder="Салон">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" name="adreses[@i].value" class="form-control" value="@adreses[i].value" placeholder="Салон">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="btn btn-danger col-sm-12 row-del">X</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Это вырезка из представления, которая должна натолкнуть Вас на мысль о том, что коллекция для удачного преобразования во View должна иметь вид "***имя_параметра_совпадающее_с_именем_в_модели***[**индекс**].**поле**".

Непосредственно для Вашего примера: ***model***.**Orders**[**i**].*UserName*,
где ***model*** - это имя параметра, принимаемое в обработчике формы:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditAutosalon(IndexViewModel model)
```

Comment: offtop: Не пойму, сложно пометить ответ решением?