# Как реализовать форму для отношения один ко многим Asp MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Не первый день бьюсь над  проблемой создания формы для отношения один ко многим.

Есть постановщики (стараюсь максимально сократить код).

```
public class Supplier
{
    [Display(Name = "SupplierID")]
    [Key]
    public int SupplierID { set; get; }

    [Display(Name = "Коммерческое название")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    public string Name { set; get; }

    public virtual ICollection<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
}
```

У постановщиков может быть много менеджеров.
Класс менеджеров.

```
public class Manager
{
    [Display(Name = "ManagerID")]
    [Key]
    public int ManagerID { set; get; }

    [Display(Name = "ФИО")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}
```

У менеджеров может быть много телефонных номеров.

```
public class Phone
{

    [Display(Name = "PhoneID")]
    [Key]
    public int PhoneID { set; get; }

    [Display(Name = "Номер Телефона")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    [Column(TypeName = "char")]
    public string PhoneNumber { set; get; }
}
```

На основе этих трех классов я создал базу.

Для отображения создал `ModelView` (прошу не обращать внимания на сервисы и селекты, все это работает и не вызывает каких-то вопросов)

```
public class SupplierDetailView
{
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public int[] SelectedServicesIds { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Service> Services { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
}
```

Для редактирования Постановщика я создал контроллер. Здесь начинаются проблемы.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var supplier = db.Suppliers.Find(id);
    var managers = db.Managers;
    var services = db.Services.Select(s => new
    {
       ServiceID = s.ServiceID,
       Service_Name = s.Service_Name
    }).ToList();
    var supplier_services = supplier.Services;

    ViewBag.Services = new MultiSelectList(services, "ServiceID",
     "Service_Name", supplier_services.Select(s => s.ServiceID).ToArray());

    var model = new SupplierDetailView
    {
      Supplier = supplier,
      Managers = managers
    };

    return PartialView("_Supplier_Edit", model);
}
```

Проблема начинается при попытке все это вывести во View.

1) Как мне отобразить данные в TextBox если их нет?

```
@model Jumper.ViewModel.SupplierDetailView
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Supplier", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "ui form" }))
{
    <div class="two fields">
        <div class="field">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Supplier.ShortName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Supplier.ShortName)
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Supplier.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Supplier.Name)
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Например, по постановщику в форме нет данных ShortName, поэтому форма не отобразит это поле. Мне нужно, чтобы отобразила. Не могу понять как выводить Менеджеров в этой форме. Делаю это так.

```
foreach (var manager in Model.Supplier.Managers)
{
    <div class="two fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label>ФИО</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => manager.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="field"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="two fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Телефон</label>
            @foreach (var phone in manager.Phones)
            {
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => phone.PhoneNumber)
            }
        </div>
```

2) Здесь такая же проблема. Если ФИО есть, а телефона нет, то не будет показываться поле для редактирования или добавления данных телефона. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502185/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80-asp-net-mvc-5/503061#503061 Я уже подробно отвечал, не совсем тот пример, но начать стоит отсюда!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Например, по постановщику в форме нет данных ShortName, поэтому форма не отобразит это поле. Мне нужно, чтобы отобразила. Не могу понять как выводить Менеджеров в этой форме.

Можно воспользоваться таким относительно безболезненным способом:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Supplier.ShortName, new { @Value = Model.Supplier.ShortName ?? "какое-то значение по умолчанию" })
```

> Здесь такая же проблема. Если ФИО есть, а телефона нет, то не будет показываться поле для редактирования или добавления данных телефона. Как мне это сделать?

Тут можно добавить немного серверной логики:

```
@if(Model.Phones.Any()) 
{
    @foreach (var phone in manager.Phones)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => phone.PhoneNumber)
    }
}
else 
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NewPhoneNumber)
}
```

и определить в модели свойство `NewPhoneNumber`, которое будет использоваться в случае, если коллекция `Phones` пуста.

Comment: и определить в модели свойство NewPhoneNumber, которое будет использоваться в случае, если коллекция Phones пуста. Пожалуйста , а можно пример?